# Django multiple contexts within a single view

Tags: python, django

I want to have something like this, where the context draws from multiple models used in a single view. How is this possible?

```
def productpage(request, product_image_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_image_id)
    image = get_object_or_404(Image, pk=product_image_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/productpage.html', {'product': product}, {'image':image})
```

this code is invalid as it stands but exemplifies what I am looking to do

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have almost got it right. Just change

```
return render(request, 'polls/productpage.html', {'product': product}, {'image':image})
```

to

```
return render(request, 'polls/productpage.html', {'product': product, 'image':image})
```